Bond length data in ClF5
Chlorine pentafluoride ($\ce{ClF_5}$) has an $sp³d²$ hybrid chlorine atom and thus the electronic geometry around Chlorine is supposed to be octahedral, with a lone pair and five bond pairs. Due to the symmetry in an octahedral geometry, it is expected that all five $\ce{Cl-F}$ bond lengths should be equal. However, as per experimental data, the basal bonds and the axial bond differ in bond length, the basal bond length being 167 pm and the axial bond length being 157 pm.
What is the reason behind this?


In an octahedral geometry, it is expected that all five Cl−F bond lengths should be equal? Not necessarily, and this isn't octahedral - there's only 5 substituents... And in reality there's no such thing as $sp³d²$ hybrid.

Octahedral molecular geometries can result in equidistant atoms, as you state. However, while the electron domain geometry is octahedral, the molecular geometry is actually square planar. Ideally, square planar geometries result in bond angles of 90° between the basal and apical atoms. There is however, a lone pair on the chlorine, which results in lone pair-bond pair repulsion, causing angles smaller than 90° between the basal F and the apical F. Research (1) on various $\ce{ClF_n}$ compounds have provided some good evidence for this, indicating that the $\ce{F_{base}-Cl-F_{apex}}$ angle is closer to 85.5° (analogous in this sense to other square pyramidal halogen pentafluorides, such as in $\ce{BrF5}$). It therefore follows that this reduction of angle brings all the basal fluorines closer together to each other. To minimize the associated repulsion, their bond lengths elongate.
The fluorine at the apex is well away from this lone pair and other bond pairs, and so remains unaffected and quite comfortably at a distance of approximately 1.59Å from the chlorine, without much bond pair repulsion. This is proved by the study through the example of the T-shaped $\ce{ClF3}$ molecule, where the $\ce{Cl-F_{apex}}$ bond length remains the same in both $\ce{ClF3}$ and $\ce{ClF5}$. Indeed, if the molecular geometry was actually octahedral (say, by the addition of another atom of fluorine), computational data suggests distances between basal and apical fluorines should be equidistant, and experimental data suggests similar findings cationic or anionic forms of $\ce{ClF6}$. There are some interesting characterizations performed on these molecules (2)(3) which I have referenced below.

Chen, L., Woon, D. E., Dunning, T. H.; J. Phys. Chem. A, Vol. 113, No. 45, 2009
Christe, K. O., Wilson, W. W., Chirakal, R. V., Sanders, J. C. P., & Schrobilgen, G. J.; Inorg. Chem., Vol. 29, No. 18, 1990
Christe, K. O., Wilson, W. W., & Curtis, E. C.; Inorg. Chem., Vol. 22, No. 21, 1983


Do we have ClF6? You mean the cation maybe?

@OscarLanzi Good catch, thanks. No, $\ce{ClF6}$ does not exist in its neutral form. I did find some interesting characterizations of both cationic and anionic forms of the molecule, and while these did not contain experimentally-determined bond length data (computationally determined data is in the paper I linked), most results seem to agree that the molecule is octahedral with very little or even no distortions in their salt forms.

Axial bonds are closer to equatorial bonds. Axial bonds are 90 degrees from equatorial bonds while equatorial bonds are 120 degrees from axial bonds. This means axial bonds exhibit more electron repulsion repelling electrons further and giving longer bond length
Axial bonds are vertical bonds (240pm) while equatorial are horizontal bonds (202pm)
Also hybridization is a concept used to ease any confusion in covalent bonding but it is not accurate. For example d orbitals have almost no involvement in main group bonding.
